# php Mongo DB MongoConnectionException' with message 'the connection has been terminated, and this cursor is dead

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get all records from a collection which has 5000 recs and loop through each record and do some operation and move it to another collection.

However after processing about 1100 recs , I get the following error

'MongoConnectionException' with message 'the connection has been terminated, and this cursor is dead'

How can I resolve ?

Comment: Can you please share a sample document and also describe the "operation" you are trying to do on it?  Or even better share the query you are running.  This will help others help you.

Comment: I am doing several operations like creating creating a few fields based on existing fields etc

Answer (score 0):

Mongo cursor timeout could be the reason. Set MongoCursor::$timeout=-1 for keeping cursor alive

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this:

```
$mongoConn = new \MongoClient('mongodb://ip:port', ['socketTimeoutMS' => 120000]);
$mongoConn->connect();
$collection = $mongoConn->selectCollection('database_name', 'collection_name');
$cursor = $collection->find();
$cursor->timeout(120000);
while ($cursor->hasNext()) {
    $record = $cursor->getNext();
    //...
}
$mongoConn->close();
```

But you still can get an error "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded". This can be solved too:

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", '60');
```

or

```
set_time_limit (60);
```

or write in .htaccess:

```
php_value max_execution_time 60
```

But it's bad decisions. Sooner or later, the script does not run out of time to complete and you will get the same error. I would recommend you use indexes: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/